# Can I set ~/.ssh/config to look up dynamic EC2 hostnames?

Tags: amazon-ec2, openssh, ssh-config

I have an EC2 instance on a dynamic IP, and it isn't doing any sort of DDNS to keep a public hostname pointed at it. I'd like to set up a shortcut in my `ssh_config` for the server, and ask `aws` CLI to tell me what the IP or hostname is.

```bash
aws ec2 describe-instances \
    --filters Name=key-name,Values=FOO \
    --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].PublicDnsName' \
    --output 'text'
```

This returns something like `ec2-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.compute-X.amazonaws.com`. But I can't work out how to get SSH to delegate the public IP or hostname resolution out to the `aws` command.

- I see various people have [scripts for generating an `ssh_config` from `aws`](https://github.com/gianlucaborello/aws-ssh-config), but I have other stuff in there that I'd rather not lose if a script were to tinker with the file.
- Some other people have [shell aliases to use instead of `ssh`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21427877/241211), but that makes complications for other services that rely on SSH specifically.

I'd also *prefer* not to use an external script if possible.

```bash
Host FOO ec2-FOO
    User ec2-user
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/creds/some.pem

    # Irrelevant?
    Hostname example.com

    # Neither alternative below works (assume full `aws` command)
    ProxyCommand bash -c 'ssh -i %i %u@$(aws ec2 describe-instances …)'
    ProxyCommand nc "$(aws ec2 describe-instances …)" %p
```

Note that `%i` used above to specify `IdentityFile` is [not a valid token for `ProxyCommand`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ssh_config.5.html#TOKENS).

### Related questions

- Stack Overflow: [Amazon EC2 hostnames](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18836503/241211)
- Server Fault: [Dynamically generate SSH Host entries in `~/.ssh/config`](https://serverfault.com/a/536934/115583)
- Unix & Linux: [Configure SSH to read `HostName` for a Host from a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/625121/143088)

  ```bash
  ProxyCommand ssh -p %p "$(aws ec2 describe-instances …)" nc localhost %p
  ```

  This might hold the answer, but I can't get it working.

Answer (score 3):

This breaks some of the requirements in the question and will not be accepted:

You can use the `Include` keyword to add a separate `ssh_config` file that you update with a script. It prevents your main configuration from getting clobbered by a bad run of the script.

```sh
# Primary ~/.ssh/config
Include config-ec2
```

```sh
# Periodically regenerated ssh_config at ~/.ssh/config-ec2
Host FOO ec2-FOO
    User ec2-user
    HostName ec2-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.compute-X.amazonaws.com

    # Figuring out how to specify a different pem for
    # each connection is still troublesome.
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/creds/some.pem
```

On the plus side, this lets you keep `ProxyCommand` available for actual proxying.